How does the Python Interpreter check thread duration?
My understanding is that historically, the python Interpreter counted lines of code executed and switched threads after a fixed amount. This was then changed to being time dependent.
What I am trying to figure out is how is the time checked for the current threads running duration? Does time duration get called after every line is executed?

See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61d3ab32da92e70bb97a544d76ef2b837501024f/Python/lock.c for the implementation. Looks like there's a separate unlocking thread.

It has never been lines of code executed - that's not something the interpreter can easily access.  Instead, it has traditionally been the number of bytecode instructions executed, with the default value being 100 as I recall (but I'm sure that value has changed over the years, and has always been adjustable via the sys module).  With the change to a time-based thread switch interval, I would guess that the check is still in the same place, at the top of the bytecode-executing loop, but I couldn't find it in a quick look.

If you check it every time a byte code operation is executed, isn't that highly inefficient?
